# The best way to run 200 threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Previously, I used the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < config.threads; i++)
{
  Thread thread = new Thread(workThread);
  thread.IsBackground = true;
  thread.Start();
}

public static void workThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // work, 10 second
    }
}
```

It works fine, but after 10-15 cycles, begins to work less. Then I wrote a class for the creation of the separate threads:

```
class ThreadsPool
{
    private static int maxThreads = 0;
    private static Thread[] threadsArray;
    private static int activeThread = 0;


    public static void Initializer(int maxThreads)
    {
        ThreadsPool.maxThreads = maxThreads;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(Program.workThread);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
        Thread threadDaemon = new Thread(Daemon);
        threadDaemon.IsBackground = true;
        threadDaemon.Start();
    }

    public static void activeThreadMinus()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref activeThread);
    }

    private static void Daemon()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(activeThread < maxThreads)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(Program.workThread);
                thread.IsBackground = true;
                thread.Start();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }

public static void workThread()
       {
            while (true)
            {
                // work 10 sec
                ThreadsPool.activeThreadMinus();
            }
        }
}
```

But the problem is that this class creates a memory leak.
Do you realize I have to do the work of 10 seconds, an almost infinite number of times, sometimes the number of running threads changes. How this can be done without memory leaks, and without losing performance.

Comment: At first what are you doing, that you need up to 200 Threads? I think this is a design problem. You will always gain performance issues if you have 200 Threads running. No Prozessor can handle this in a fast manner.

Comment: I need to process image. I know the threads 200 is not impossible.

Comment: Don't break into 200 threads. Break into the number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores.

Comment: May be you need a thread pool instead?

Comment: The TPL (`Parallel.For`) and PLINQ (`enumerable.AsParallel()`) frameworks will, by default, process your data using an appropriate number of threads (I think it's the number of logical cores * 2).

Comment: The [TPL DataFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tpl-dataflow) framework is a suitable librairie for such an image processing.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a queue and have as many threads as number of processors. Then make the threads read from the queue and process the messages. Don't destroy the threads, let them run indefinitely.